# ObjC code in Android using ndk under Linux

Tags: android, objective-c, linux, android-ndk, centos

I am trying to implement this under Linux,
**Adding Objective C Support to the Android NDK**

I took some references from here

http://blog.vucica.net/2011/06/developing-objective-c-apps-for-android-using-mac-os-x.html

but it doesn't compile, since the binaries are for OS-X

So after that I decided to compile the ndk-tools for Linux, following this link

http://michael.f1337.us/2011/11/19/rebuilding-the-android-ndk-for-objective-c-support/

first error I got , was missing --mpc-version info, which could be added manually in the build-gcc.sh file,
Now I am stuck at the next step, where I am getting this error

Error:

“Fixing Google Bug Copying from /home/SDKs/Android/toolchain-src/binutils/binutils-2.22.51/binutils/sysinfo.h to /tmp/ndk-root/build/toolchain/binutils-2.22.51/binutils/sysinfo.h”

Building : arm-linux-androideabi-4.6.1 toolchain [this can take a long time].
Error while building toolchain. See /tmp/ndk-root/build/toolchain/config.log

**which further says** :

configure: error: in `/tmp/ndk-root/build/toolchain/libbfd-binutils-2.22.51':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

If anyone ever came across this or has any information regarding this, please share..
thanks a lot !!

Comment: A search for ["C compiler cannot create executables"](https://www.google.com/search?q=C+compiler+cannot+create+executables) reveals many results, some of them may be relevant for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuild latest NDK for supporting ObjC, just from vanilla. So, you need just perform 2 scripts and change 2 files in NDK.

for download toolchain
./download-toolchain-sources.sh

and rebuild gcc, but don't forget to modify it.
./build-gcc.s

What the files you need to modify, you can find on page http://michael.f1337.us/2011/11/19/rebuilding-the-android-ndk-for-objective-c-support/